# jQuery datepicker, onSelect Second input date select change the First input date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 date (Dep & Return) inputs and inline date-picker calendar which shows in bootstrap modal when click on each input

```
<input type="text" id="DepDate" name="DepDate" class="form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" readonly />
<input type="text" id="returnDate" name="returnDate" class="form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" readonly  />
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="datepicker"></div> // Inline Calendar
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $('#DepDate, #returnDate').datepicker({ //Both inputs have dates but calendar turns `off`
        dateFormat: 'd-M-yy',
        showOn: "off"
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { //Bootstrap Modal event to fetch the respective input id
        var Dateid = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('id');
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'd-M-yy',
            minDate: 0,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thr', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) { //ON Select Function
                var dateMin = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
                if (Dateid === 'DepDate') { //If Depart Date
                    var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 1);
                    var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 7);
                    $('input[name="DepDate"]').val($(this).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'd-M-yy'
                    }).val());
                    $('input[name="returnDate"]').val($.datepicker.formatDate('d-M-yy', new Date(rMax)));
                } else if (Dateid === 'returnDate') { //If Return Date
                    $('input[name="returnDate"]').val($(this).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'd-M-yy'
                    }).val());
                }
                $("#myModal").modal("hide"); //Hide Modal After Date Selection
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Goals are:

1. Both inputs get dates from inline calendar from modal.
2. Dep & Return dates must have 7 days difference when `DepDate` Selected.
3. If selected `DepDate` is greater then current date then dates before selected `DepDate` must be disabled.

First 2 Goals are achieved but the Problem is;

- When click on `ReturnDate` input and select date from inline calendar, it replaced the Selected `DepDate` then add 7 days difference and show selected `ReturnDate` as `DepDate` and insert new date as `ReturnDate` in date inputs.

What I'm missing and how can I fix this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cvex4e8/1/)

Comment: where you use rMin and rMax?

Comment: in if & else condition, first `if (Dateid === 'DepDate') {` check the code line before closing bracket `}`, the `$('input[name="returnDate"]').val`

Comment: i see, but you only declare it, not use!

Comment: Did both declared and used when selected dep date but problem is in return date when return date selected it actually replace selected dep date you can check the fiddle and see the problem

Comment: my guess is problem is not with calendar or inputs, problem is with modal, it is not removing the old data when closed